# Wrapping DOM element or using a utility class

Tags: javascript

I am working on a custom js library for creating UI components and I would like to know (and understand) the repercussions of the following two approaches:

(the code below is just to show the concept)

First approach is by encapsulating the element:

```
function wrapElement(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    return {
        el:el,
        hide:function() {
          // set el.style.display to 'none'
        },
        show:function() {
           // set el.style.display to ''
        },
        getSize:function() {
           // get the size of the el
        }   
    }
}

var myEl = wrapElement('abc');
myEl.hide();
```

The second approach is to manipulate the element by a utility class:

```
var ElementUtil = {
    get:function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    },
    hide:function(el) {
        // set the el.style.display to 'none'
    },
    show:function(el) {
        // set the el.style.display to ''
    },
    getSize:function(el) {
        // get the size of the el
    }
}

var myEl = ElementUtil.get('abc');
ElementUtil.hide(myEl);
```

Which one of the above is better if we take the memory consumption and performance into account?

(Please note: I don't want to use a pre existing library like jQuery and such)

Any advice or directions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd take the first approach, compare `ElementUtil.hide(myEl);ElementUtil.show(myEl)` to something like `wrapElement('abc').hide().show()`

Comment: My concern with the first approach is that if I have many elements that I need to manipulate then I would be creating a lot of "overhead" objects. Any opinion on that?

Comment: You can use a constructor function and share the methods in the prototype with all instances.

Comment: I always read that extending the DOM element by adding custom behavior to the prototype is a bad thing to do and not always cross browser compatible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is going to take more memory. Each time you wrap an object, you are creating an extra pointer to the element "el" plus 3 functions. You are creating those functions EVERY time you wrap an ID.

The second solution creates the functions only once, and returns the pointer to the element to the caller, so you are saving more memory and time.

Comment: So if I go with the second option then I have no real way of saving meta information on the given element except to adding el.mydata = {..} to the element itself. Is there any downside to doing that?

Comment: That is what jQuery does, but they have spent a lot of time writing that library in order to help prevent memory leaks. They also chose a hybrid of your approach. Instead of keeping one element, they keep a collection (which is used very often!) but then they put the methods in a prototype (or other object) so that they aren't created every time you wrap.

Comment: I am inclined to go with the second approach. The only thing that worries me are the attached event handlers. Especially when elements are removed.

Comment: You should definitely be concerned, because it is a big, big undertaking. I am very curious why you are so against jQuery, when it provides all of the functionality you are talking about plus it has been debugged and tested for years. Or any other library that has done the same. Also, please accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am planning to build a new js application framework (yeah, we need another one :-) ). At this moment I am investigating the possibilities. I am definitely not against jquery. I read that angular is using a cut-down version of it. Since I am not going to support older browsers I would like to know how much this event thing is going to be a problem.

Comment: Supporting older browsers is the problem, so not supporting them will make your life much easier. I would recommend reading jQuery to get ideas. For instance, they store all event handler and custom data in a field that can be easily removed when the dom element itself is removed. Something like that would be essential.